# Is there a way to use selection sort with randomized captalized letters?

Tags: python, selection-sort

So Ive been working on a code to convert hexadecimal to ASCII then sort the letters with selection sort. But when I get a input such as HBbmYa, it outputs as B,H,Y,a,b,m. It should output as a,B,b,H,m,Y or a,B,b,H,m,y. Is there a way to solve this problem? Here is the code i have right now.

```
#ask for input
hex_str = input("Write hexadecimal string here without spaces: ")
#format the input so it doesn't have any spaces or commas for the code to work
hex_str = hex_str.replace("," , "")
hex_str = hex_str.replace(" " , "")
#convert input to ASCII
def hexToASCII(hexx): 
    # initialize the ASCII code string as empty. 
    asci = "" 
    for i in range(0, len(hexx), 2): 
        # extract two characters from hex string 
        part = hexx[i : i + 2] 
        # change it into base 16 and 
        # typecast as the character  
        ch = chr(int(part, 16)) 
        # add this char to final ASCII string 
        asci += ch 
    return asci 
#function call
ascii_output = hexToASCII(hex_str)
# print the ASCII string.
print("ASCII output is: {}".format(ascii_output))


def selectionSort(u):
    sortedarry = []
    def findSmallest(l):
        x = l[0]
        for i in l:
            [ascii_output.lower() for ascii_output in u]
            if i < x:
                x = i
        return l.index(x)
    while len(u) > 0:
        x = findSmallest(u)
        sortedarry.append(u.pop(x))
    return sortedarry

u = list(ascii_output)
sortedarry = selectionSort(u)

# print the sorted array
print("The sorted array is: {}".format(sortedarry))
```

Comment: What is the problem? The commas?

Comment: Please provide the expected output

Comment: Why are you writing your own sort routine and your own hex converter?  Python already has both of these.

Comment: The reason for my own code is that this if for a project and my teacher doesn't allow us to use the built-in functions. Just our own code.

Answer (score 0):

In your `findSmallest` function, you could use a case insensitive comparison by lowercasing the two elements you compare:

```
def findSmallest(l):
    x = l[0]
    for i in l:
        if i.lower() < x.lower():
            x = i
    return l.index(x)
```